# Jackson-jr read polymorphic ArrayList

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Jackson-jr to read my JSON files. One of them is a bit complex:

```
[
 {"test-1":["a","b","c","d"]},
 {"test-2":["b","j","d"]},
 {"test-3":["n","e","o","p","i"]},
 {"test-4":["s","a","v","z","b","ç","x","p"]},
 {"test-5":["d","q","u"]},
 {"test-6":["f","b"]}
]
```

My code to read is very simple:

```
InputStream inputStream   = assetManager.open("test.json");
ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>> arrays = JSON.std.beanFrom(ArrayList.class, inputStream);
```

My intention is to get each array to work with each of them:

```
arrays.get(i);
```

But, when this line is executed I have an Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.fasterxml.jackson.jr.ob.impl.DeferredMap cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap
```

Jackson-jr doesn't have TypeFactory, TypeReference or ObjectMapper. Some links that I found answers for jackson, not for jackson-jr:

[ClassCastException when convert json to list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816242/classcastexception-when-convert-json-to-list-of-objects)

[Jackson custom deserializer for one field with polymorphic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27351698/jackson-custom-deserializer-for-one-field-with-polymorphic-types?rq=1)

[Tricky(?) JSON, polymorphic deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691074/tricky-json-polymorphic-deserialization?rq=1)

Is there a say to handle this in Jackson-Jr?

Comment: Define `arrays` as `List<Map<String, List<String>>> arrays`

Comment: You save the day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should program to the interface and not to implementation classes. As the returned Map implementation is `DeferredMap` and not `HashMap`, you get the `ClassCastException`. Change the assignment as below

```
List<Map<String, List<String>>> arrays = JSON.std.beanFrom(ArrayList.class, inputStream);
```

Comment: In addition, instead of `beanFrom`, method to use should likely be `listOfFrom`, as the result is a `List`, not Bean. If so, type would be `Map.class`.